# How to remove the 'pairwise test' text on the right-hand side of the graph in ggstatsplot

Tags: ggstatsplot

i am having difficulty removing the text on the right hand side of my graph (pairwise test:Dunn, bars shown: not significant). can anyone help?

```
plot1 <- ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
  data = boxplot.Age,
  x = cluster,
  y = Age,
  color = group,
  title = "Age Box Plot",
  subtitle = "Grouped by cluster", type="nonparametric", comparisons_correction = "holm",results.subtitle =FALSE,   pairwise.display = 'none')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANBd9.png)

I tried to use the argument pairwise.display = 'none' but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the ggstatsplot GitHub page ([Issue #864](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/864#issuecomment-1583438594)), the secondary y-axis title can be removed by entering this as an argument to ggbetweenstats:

```
gplot.component = list(theme(axis.title.y.right = element_blank(), 
axis.text.y.right = element_blank(), 
axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank())
```

Alternatively, my preference would be to just add the component via the ggplot + syntax:

```
ggbetweenstats() +
theme(axis.title.y.right = element_blank(), 
axis.text.y.right = element_blank(), 
axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `pairwise.comparisons = FALSE` and that should turn off pairwise comparisons and will also remove the secondary axis label:

```r
plot1 <- ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
  data = boxplot.Age,
  x = cluster,
  y = Age,
  color = group,
  title = "Age Box Plot",
  subtitle = "Grouped by cluster", 
  type = "nonparametric", 
  pairwise.comparisons = FALSE,
  results.subtitle = FALSE
)
```